# How to solve 'HttpVersionNotSupported' errors in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I tried to store a large file, I got this error:

**Message: S3::putObject(): [HttpVersionNotSupported] The HTTP version specified is not supported.**

Comment: Note the `HttpVersionNotSupported` error will also occur when *downloading* a file from S3 with spaces pin it - the workaround is the same (remove the spaces)

Comment: You can replace the space character with %20 if there is a space that needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue in Codeigniter S3, the problem was while sending the filename parameter in `$this->s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "examplebucketname", $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)` if there are any spaces in destination filename then this occurs.

Comment: HOw you resolved the above issue if file name have space